# Cannot set the fix size of youtube video

Tags: apache-flex, youtube

I am trying to use youtube video inside adobe flex. I have added the video to the canvas but i cannot fix the size of the video. It is also render in full width and height. Below is my code.

Code on pastebin http://pastebin.com/hN3NHRpp

```
<mx:Canvas width="380" height="250" id="uplayer" />

public function init(){
   _uic = UIComponent(uplayer.addChild (new UIComponent ()));
   _uic.width = 380;
   _uic.width = 250;

   _loader = new Loader();
   _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoadInit);
   var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/v/2030agUM_JY?version=2&autoplay=1&fs=0&hd=1");
   _loader.load(request);
}

private function onLoadInit(event:Event):void {
                        _player = _loader.content;

                _playerObject = _player as DisplayObject;

        //_playerObject.addEventListener("jwplayerReady", onPlayerReady);

             //   RootReference.root = _playerObject.root;

                _uic.addChild(_loader);
                        _uic.width = 380;
                        _uic.width = 250;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you need to use the `setSize()` method of the youtube player:

In your `onLoadInit()` event handler, you need to add additional event listeners to `_loader.content` (or your `_player` variable which is the same object). In particular you need to listen for the `onReady` event, and in the handler for the `onReady` event you can set the size with `_player.setSize(380,250)`.

I'm sure it will work if you follow the code/example that is given in the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference#Loading).